# Redgate ANT performance profiler seems to get stuck in an infinite loop while profiling even though the app never goes into an infinite loop

Tags: redgate, red-gate-ants

I run ANT profiler pointing it at IIS with my credentials. When i start profiling, the home page comes up, but when I hit a certain page, ANT just seems to get stuck in some infinite loop trying to profile the application.

I can highlight the current area, and i see 80 million hits to an unknown method(which seems to be where ants gets stuck)

I can stop ANTS, navigate to the site and that same page that causes ants to get stuck, and all is well. I have seen ANTs do this from time to time, but never 10 times in a row.

Normally, i can reset IIS, and restart the ANTS service and tool and viola it will start working again, and not get into the infinite loop.

is there a known bug/workaround for this type of issue

Comment: When you say your credentials are you running IIS5 - thus using the username/password option in ANTS? What do you mean by an "Unknown" method? Have yo checked the log file? (Help Menu > Logs folder) You may also want to consider contacting Red Gate support: support@red-gate.com

Comment: @DeneB Yes, using the username/password option in ANTS. Unknown means in the call tree it shows a grayed out 'unknown method' that's what it says. I'm betting the profiling code is getting in an infinite loop.

Comment: I would contact support. Send them the results file / log if you are able